# Build for android freezes in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, sdk

I finished creating my game and when  tried to build it for android, every time I build it the build process freezes for hours and nothing happens, even unity stops responding to me, so I kill it from taskmng... it works fine for windows but can't build for andriod, anyway I tried to re-install unity and update it(to 2018.2.10f1 (personal)) but it still doesn't work. And I'm not ready to re-download the SDK with all that size....

[image: An image to the problem]

**Edit:** I solved the problem... As I thought, the problem was related to the Android SDK... So unfortunately I had to re download it from zero

Comment: Have you tried building an empty scene?

Comment: @Jax297 Yes, and unfortunately I faced the same problem...

Comment: On which part does it stop?
Some people tried disabling different settings (lightning, post processing etc.), have you tried any of that?

Comment: @Jax297 on "Task generateReleaseResource" as in the picture... I solved it by re-downloading the android SDK.... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem...
As I thought, the problem was related to the Android SDK... So unfortunately I had to re download it from zero